# Adding a column to a dataframe based on labels from a different dataframe

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R and I hope somebody can help me with this problem. There're two dataframes I am working on. First one:

```
> print(averagetable)
   Group.1     Moving   Feeding  Standing classification
1 cluster1 0.04978355 0.1470238 0.7795848 Moving/Feeding
2 cluster2 0.08214286 0.3216518 0.5642857 Feeding/Moving
3 cluster3 0.03750000 0.1462121 0.7922980       Standing
```

`head()` sample of the second one:

```
> head(tableresults)
  ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z Vigilance Head-up Grazing Browsing Moving Grooming Resting
1         19         21         28         1       0       0        0      0        0       0
2         20         14         24         1       0       0        0      0        0       0
3         34         35         49         1       0       0        0      0        0       0
4         18          5         19         1       0       0        0      0        0       0
5         23         27         35         1       0       0        0      0        0       0
6         33         20         39         1       0       0        0      0        0       0
  Fleeing Total     Event winning_cluster
1       0     1 Vigilance        cluster3
2       0    80 Vigilance        cluster3
3       0    80 Vigilance        cluster3
4       0    80 Vigilance        cluster1
5       0    80 Vigilance        cluster3
6       0    80 Vigilance        cluster3
```

I would like to add a column `tableresults$classification` containing the categories of `averagetable$classification` depending on the cluster name in `tableresults$winning_cluster`.

The labels for each cluster are summarized in `averagetable$Group.1` and `averagetable$classification`. The rest of the columns in both dataframes don't have a particular importance on the final output.

A `head()` sample of the final output would be:

```
> head(tableresults)
  ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z Vigilance Head-up Grazing Browsing Moving Grooming Resting
1         19         21         28         1       0       0        0      0        0       0
2         20         14         24         1       0       0        0      0        0       0
3         34         35         49         1       0       0        0      0        0       0
4         18          5         19         1       0       0        0      0        0       0
5         23         27         35         1       0       0        0      0        0       0
6         33         20         39         1       0       0        0      0        0       0
  Fleeing Total     Event winning_cluster classification
1       0     1 Vigilance        cluster3  Standing
2       0    80 Vigilance        cluster3  Standing
3       0    80 Vigilance        cluster3  Standing
4       0    80 Vigilance        cluster1  Moving/Feeding
5       0    80 Vigilance        cluster3  Standing
6       0    80 Vigilance        cluster3  Standing
```

This is a bit confusing to me so I hope somebody can help me. Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

tableresults %>%
  inner_join(averagetable %>% select(Group.1,classification),by = c("winning_cluster" = "Group.1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr you can do a join:

`library(dplyr)
df_final = tableresults%>%
  left_join(averagetable, by =c('winning_cluster' = ' Group.1')%>% # does the join
  select(-Moving, - Feeding, -Standing) #unselect uncalled columns`

If there are winning groups in the table_results table that do not have a classification in the averagetable, it will populate with null.

Answer (score 0):

A base R approach:

```
merge(tableresults, averagetable[,c(1,5)], 
      by.x="winning_cluster", by.y="Group.1", all.x=TRUE)
```